# Bluetooth audio streaming from Android to Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, android

Is there any way I can Stream Audio from my Android device via Bluetooth to my Macbook Pro?

I'm using OS X 10.9.1 and Android 4.4.2.

The AUX-Port on my Android device has stopped working. Is there a way to stream audio to my Mac so that I can play audio on my Android device through my Mac's speakers?

Comment: What Android device are you talking about, what version? What version of Mac OS X are you running? I'm missing some details here.

Comment: @Robuust Mac Version 10.9.1 , Andriod Version - 4.4.2

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to stream Bluetooth audio **to** a Mac, but, _I could be wrong_. I use the [JBL Flip](http://reviews.cnet.com/bluetooth-speakers/jbl-flip-black/4505-34810_7-35550919.html) bluetooth speakers and I think they're amazing for the size and convenience and decently priced.

Answer (score 3):

After 6 years, I finally found a solution. Use [sndcpy](https://github.com/rom1v/sndcpy) with [ADB over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp).

Ensure that you have [USB Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103117/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-in-android) on and Install via USB on.

If `vlc` is not found even though you installed VLC Media Player, then you can set an environment variable in your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` by adding a new line:

```
export VLC="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC"
```

If you encounter this exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: You need the android.permission.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS permission to use the PackageManager.INSTALL_GRANT_RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS flag
```

then open `sndcpy` bash script in a code editor and remove the `-g` flag from the two `adb install` commands.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is not to use Bluetooth but Wi-Fi nowadays, although it is not explained anywhere.

Connect to the same Wi-Fi network your Mac is connected to.

First one needs to download the [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com/Mac) Mac app which is not free. It is the only app or option that has worked for me though. Install and open it, open preferences and click the Google Cast option.

Second: on android, use the Samsung Music app, for instance, as it plays a tune find and hit the "play" icon that's within two arrows (Smart View), it looks like a repeat button but it's not, cast to your Mac. It works straight ahead but no other program does that, and the Bluetooth streaming option doesn't work on my own Android.

Although I haven't tried it yet, you can also try [AirDroid Cast](https://www.airdroid.com/en/download/airdroid-cast/), that you need to to install on Android and on the Mac separately.